# Implement IEnumerable in Fsharp on external type

Tags: f#, ienumerable, sequence, anonymous-types

I am trying to implement a ToEnumerable property on an external type that does not implement it. I can't quite get the code to work.

So I dumbed it down to adding a untyped **GetEnumerator** property, and added the code for ToComparable for guidance. However, I have no idea on how to store the mutable state for the counter.

Is the pb the anonymous class ?

How would you do it ?

```
open System
open System.Collections
open System.Collections.Generic

type Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element with
     //**WORKS OK**
     member this.ToComparable:IComparer<Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element> =   { 
        new IComparer<Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element> with 
           member this.Compare(x, y) = x.NumValues.CompareTo(y.NumValues) 
     }

     //**WORKS (sort of) OK without storing the state**
     member this.GetEnumerator2:IEnumerator =  {
        //let mutable i =0
        new IEnumerator with
              member this2.Reset() = 
                 i <- 0;
                 ()
              member this2.MoveNext() = 
                 if i < n then 
                    i <- i + 1
                    true
                 else
                    false
              member this2.Current 
                 with get() =
                    this.GetElement(0) :> obj
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `NumValues` is the count, you could do something like this:

```
type Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element with
  member this.GetEnumerator() = 
    (Seq.init this.NumValues this.GetElement).GetEnumerator()
```

This returns `IEnumerator<'T>` where `'T` is the return type of `GetElement`.

Comment: indeed. well seen ! I am just starting fsharp, so easy to miss the picture !

Comment: one less state to keep track of ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Going back to your original idea of adding a `ToEnumerable` property to the type, I might name the property `AsEnumerable` or `AsSeq` since Seq is the F# term for IEnumerable, and implement it something like this:

```
type Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element with
    member this.AsEnumerable =
        seq { for i = 0 to this.NumValues - 1 do
                  yield this.GetElement(i) }
```

Or you could do it with `Seq.init` as Daniel suggests:

```
type Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element with
    member this.AsEnumerable =
        Seq.init this.NumValues this.GetElement
```

Comment: very good. I guess the second one is more 'functional' as it (seemingly) does not introduce any new mutable state to track. I am surprised at how the encapsulation of mutable state is enjoyable to use.